# Как в nodeJS express передать переменную полученную из request.get в ejs шаблон?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

При помощи библиотеки `request` я получаю данные `get` запросом:

```
//request.js

var request = require('request');

request.get('http://177.77.44.99:8081/gall/cesar.txt',function(error, response, body){
  console.log('error:', error);
  console.log('body:', body);
});
```

Как мне передать полученные данные (`body`) в `ejs` шаблон, например в  `$('#traceExport').html(body);`

Кусок кода app.js

`
var routes = require('./routes/index');

var users = require('./routes/users');

var user_data = require('./routes/user_data');

app.use('/', user_data.router);
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);`

Сам users.js

```
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var app = express();
router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
res.render("login", {title:"Login page"});
});
```

function handler(req, res){
request.get('http://177.77.44.99:8081/gall/cesar.txt',function(error, response, body){

```
        res.render('/roumer', {result : body})

})
```

}

router.get('roumer', handler);

Comment: Собственно а где у вас express ? Вы просто делаете запрос на сервер, это ведь не обработчик запроса.

Comment: @ uber42 Ну как бы в этом и вопрос, как мне передать результат запроса в форму на ejs.

Comment: ну так делайте запрос прямо в обработчике маршрута, а потом передавайте результат для рендеринга

Comment: @ uber42 Спасибо за ответ, но когда я использую этот код в своём примере получаю 404 ошибку, т.е. как будто не корректный путь до моей страницы(/roumer), и как это реализовать в случаи, если мне нужно отображать файл по нажатию кнопки в определённую форму, ну как ajax'oм это делать я понимаю, а как это реализовать в node js?

Comment: Вы получаете ошибку при отправке GET запроса по адресу /path ? И приложите свой код, наброски и какие ошибки в каких случаях

Comment: @ uber42 Добавил пример в вопрос

Comment: А зачем "/roumer", просто "roumer"

Comment: @ uber42 Пробовал и так, результат один, 404

Comment: `module.exports = router` такая строка прописана в users.js ?

Comment: @ uber42 Да прописана

Comment: Попробуйте зайти по адресу /users/roumer

Answer (score 1):

```
function handler(req, res){
    request.get('http://177.77.44.99:8081/gall/cesar.txt',function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            // res.redirect('/') ответ в результате ошибки
        } else { 
            res.render('name.ejs', {result : body})
        }
    })
}

app.get('path', handler);
```